# AngularJS + Provider + Webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, this

There is an angularjs application that is built by **webpack** (it also uses **babel-loader** when building).

There is a **MessageProvider.js** file with the following code:

```
const SERVER_SIDE_MESSAGE_PROVIDER = ['$injector', ($injector) => {

var localeJson = [];

this.loadLocale = (lang) => {
    ....
};

this.$get = () => {
    return {
        ....
    };
};
}];
export { SERVER_SIDE_MESSAGE_PROVIDER };
```

After successfully building the application **using webpack**, an error is displayed in the browser:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module *app name* due to:
TypeError: Cannot set property 'loadLocale' of undefined
```

Pointing to the line

```
this.loadLocale = (lang) => ....
```

Can you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: How are you registering `SERVER_SIDE_MESSAGE_PROVIDER` with AngularJS? There should be some code like `angular.service('name', SERVER_SIDE_MESSAGE_PROVIDER)` somewhere.

Comment: @JackA. I register the provider like this: `angular.module('App', [uirouter]).provider('ServerSideMessage', SERVER_SIDE_MESSAGE_PROVIDER)`

Comment: OK, just wanted to make sure you were registering it as a provider. In that case, see the answer from @brian60. As stated, arrow functions can't be used as constructors (therefore they have no `this` context). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @JackA.Yes, thanks, it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this:

```
function($injector) {
```

there is no `this` on an arrow function.